# Connecting two databases and writting in single query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, ibm-midrange

There are 2 seperate DB involved and both were phisically 2 different places.
 In my application, I used spring batch and implemented like this:

1.Fetching all ids from AS/400 database(Master DB)
2.comparing with MY SQL db (my application) ids and what ever Ids existed in sql db, I am updating those IDS information to My local DB(MY SQL).
Disadvantage :
Assume AS400 DB has 10 ids and in my Application has only 2 ids, but in order to get this data 
I am actually reading all 10 Ids. so waste of time and lack of efficiency right?!

Here is the code I am using in spring batch to fetch data :

```
<bean id="patternsItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
                    <property name="sql" value="SELECT
                                                        J3PATT AS patternId,
                                                        J3PTYP AS patternType,
                                                        J3CLAS AS PatternClass,
                                                        J3REPT AS repeat,
                                                        j3CLRS AS numOfColors,
                                                        JOENTT AS event,
                                                        J3ACT AS activity
                                                        FROM TEST006966.JQP030H a WHERE rrn(a) >=( select max(rrn(b)) from
                                                        TEST006966.JQP030H b where a.j3patt = b. j3patt) and j3sts = 'N' ORDER BY
                                                        J3PATT, JODATE desc ,jotime desc
                                                        "/>

                        <property name="rowMapper">
                                    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper">
                                                <property name="mappedClass" value="com.mohawkind.batch.patterns.PatternsRowMapper"/>
                                    </bean>
                        </property>
                        <property name="dataSource" ref="AS400DataSource" />
            </bean>

        <bean id="patternsItemWriter" class="com.mohawkind.batch.patterns.PatternsWritter" />
```

What I am looking for :

I want a solution to only fetch data what is existed in my local(SQL DB).
is it possible to connecting 2 db and fetching data through spring batch jobs??

Any ideas,suggestions will greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: In your example you mentioned 10 rows & 2 rows. Is this indicative of the volume you are expecting?  If the cardinality is low like this then reasonable strategies may be quite different than if the magnitude is thousands or millions.

Answer (score -1):

Is it not possible for you to create a database view using this query?